Calculate the whole part of $A=\frac{1012^2}{\sqrt{1*2}+\sqrt{3*4}+\cdots+\sqrt{2023*2024}}$
the question
Calculate the whole part of:
$$A=\frac{1012^2}{\sqrt{1*2}+\sqrt{3*4}+\cdots+\sqrt{2023*2024}}$$
my idea
My first thought was to to fit the number between 2 consecutive natural numbers
Using AM-GM, we get the following inequality $\sqrt{1*2}+\sqrt{3*4}+...+\sqrt{2023*2024}\leq \frac{2024*2025}{4}=506*2025$
so $\frac{1012^2}{\sqrt{1*2}+\sqrt{3*4}+...+\sqrt{2023*2024}} \geq \frac{2024}{2025}$
But now I don't know how to find $\frac{1012^2}{\sqrt{1*2}+\sqrt{3*4}+...+\sqrt{2023*2024}} \leq ????$ . I tried using again inequality but got to nothing useful
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Do you mean $A=\sqrt{1\times 2}+\sqrt{3\times 4}+...+\sqrt{2023\times 2024}$?

@JoshuaTilley Sorry, now i will edit the mistake...

You are forgetting to close the $}$ when you write $\backslash \textrm{frac}{...$

@lulu I edited the post now...sorry

I suggest computing the analogous expression for $N=2k$, with $k$ smaller than $1012$.

@lulu I dont really understand what do you mean(english is not my first language also :( )

Define $B_n=\sqrt {1\times 2}+\sqrt {3\times 4}\cdots +\sqrt {(2n-1)\times 2n}$  Then define $A_n=\frac {n^2}{B_n}$.   The answer you want is $A_{1012}$.  If you compute $A_n$ for many values of $n$ you'll quickly see the answer, though it still requires proof.

Note the denominator can be expressed as $\sum_{n=1}^{2023} \sqrt{n(n+1)}$

@Gray This isn't quite right.  That sum would be $\sqrt {1\times 2}+\sqrt {2\times 3}+\cdots$.  You need to sum only over the odd $n$ in that range.

The number of terms in the denominator of $A$ is $2023$, so the AM-GM inequality gives
$$\frac{\sqrt{1\times 2}+...+\sqrt{2023\times 2024}}{2023}\le \sqrt{2023!}^{\frac{1}{2023}}$$
A simpler bound is that $x<\sqrt{x(x+1)}< x+1$ for every term, so
$$\frac{1012^2}{1012\times 2024/2}> A> \frac{1012^2}{1012\times 2026/2}$$
where I have summed the arithmetic series $1+2+3+...+2023$ and $2+3+4+...+2024$ as upper/lower bounds to the denominator.
These are both very close to $1$, so the integer part should be clear.

Thank you for you rnaswer. I don't understand how you got to $$\frac{1012^2}{2023\times 2024/2}\ge A\ge \frac{1012^2}{2023\times 2026/2}$$? Can you be more explicit please?

Try using the bound $x\le \sqrt{x(x+1)}\le x+1$ on the sum $\sqrt{1\times 2}+...+\sqrt{2023\times 2024}$.

You will then need to know how to sum an arithmetic series.

The denominator as written has 1012 terms

Thanks, @WW1 I have edited

@JoshuaTilley isnt the whole part 0??? Correct me if im wrong!

Yes, the upper bound is $1$, and the lower bound above $0$, so the integer part is zero.

Hint: the denominator is greater than $1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + \cdots + 2023$, the sum of the first 1012 odd numbers.  What's the sum of the first $n$ odd numbers?

The idea is clear: If the denominator is decreased, the ratio increases.
$$0<A=\frac{1012^2}{\sqrt{1*2}+\sqrt{3*4}+\cdots+\sqrt{2023*2024}}<
\frac{1012^2}{\sqrt{1*1}+\sqrt{3*3}+\cdots+\sqrt{2023*2023}}=
\frac{1012^2}{1+3+\cdots+2023}
=\frac{2012^2}{2012^2}=1.
$$
So, $0<A<1$ and $\lfloor A\rfloor=0.$
